# Меню с кнопкам исчезает на IOS

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

На Андройде все работает отлично, проблема только с IOS

```
ok_cancel_menu = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True,False)
ok_cancel_menu.row('Далее⏭️','Отмена⛔')

def photo_bind_photo_step(message):
    user = user_dict[message.chat.id]
    if (message.text=="Отмена⛔"):
        cancelation(message)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите пункт меню', reply_markup=nomenclaturaMenu)
        return

    if message.content_type=='photo':
        for m in message.photo:
            fileID = m.file_id
            file_info = bot.get_file(fileID)
            downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

            with open(fileID+".jpg", 'wb') as new_file:
                new_file.write(downloaded_file)
            user.photos.append(fileID+".jpg")
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Добавьте ещё фото или нажмите Далее⏭ если закончили выбор',reply_markup = ok_cancel_menu)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, photo_bind_photo_step)
            return
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите номер объекта', reply_markup = cancel_menu)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, vvedi_nomer_objecta_step)
```

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8035828/74536332-ecf5e900-4f48-11ea-8141-e5a11ca2a477.gif